# C++, #include problem!

Tags: c++

My Includes are in a header called "stats.h"

I have 2 classes **A** and **B**.

**A** requires the header of **B** and **A** the header of **B**

When I Try to compile, I get about 50 errors like this one

```
identifier 'Player'
int assumed
; before * missing
```

Any ideads on how to fix this? :(

**(Here the relevant code)**

**CLASS A - PLAYER**

```
#include "stats.h"

class Player
{
public:
Player(int x, int y);

Texture *texture;

int x;
int y;

float rotation;

void Update(double elapsedTime);
void Draw(Sprite *sprite);

private:
Weapon *weapon;
};
```

**CLASS B - WEAPON**

```
#include "stats.h"

class Weapon // **CLASS B**
{
public:
double interval;

Weapon(Player *player);

void Update(double elapsedTime);
void Draw(Sprite *sprite);

protected:

private:
Player *player;
};
```

**STATS.H**

```
#include "Player.hpp"
#include "Weapon.hpp"
```

Comment: Why are you putting all your includes in a single header?

Comment: @Bart - sometimes is very useful - for example, when you have some common headers and you don't want to include them one by one in several other files, then you could just put the include-s into a single header and include it, instead of including several headers.

Comment: "and you don't want to include them one by one"... I would still avoid this as much as possible. You can set yourself up for a world of hurt. Or even someone who has to take over your code. Especially if it goes beyond just a couple of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have implementation in your headers, so you could pass with forward declarations and include the headers only in the cpp files.

---

For example - before `class Player`, put forward declaration of `class Weapon`:

```
//vvvvvvvvvvv
class Weapon;

class Player
{
public:
    Player(int x, int y);
    /* .. */
};
```

and remove the `#include "stats.h"`. The same for `class Weapon`

Comment: the class definition is in the header, so i need to include player.h there too

Comment: You mean, the implementation is in the header? Then separate it (:

Answer (score 0):

Although using forward declarations as others have suggested will work, your real problem is with the design. Mutual dependencies between classes like this are almost always a sign that something is wrong with the design. In this case, I would *really* want to know if Weapon needs to know about Player.